# The follow up link, to this WCF RIA Silverlight tutorial, is confusing

Tags: silverlight

Till the below it works fine

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee796239(v=vs.91).aspx#Y2918

From the below link nothing works, from where did _customer context come from?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707338(v=vs.91).aspx

Comment: Can be voted as off-topic: unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code from [Walkthrough: Creating a RIA Services Solution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707376%28v=vs.91%29.aspx) where _customerContext is defined.

```
Imports System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client
Imports RIAServicesExample.Web

Partial Public Class MainPage
    Inherits UserControl

    Private _customerContext As New CustomerDomainContext

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()

        Dim loadOp = Me._customerContext.Load(Me._customerContext.GetCustomersQuery())
        CustomerGrid.ItemsSource = loadOp.Entities
    End Sub

End Class
```